# initialize class with same type directly or through constructor

Tags: c++

I have this code:

```
#include <iostream>
template <int mult>
struct A {
    int v;
    A (int p) {
        v = p * mult;
    }
};

int main (void) {
    A<4> a (2); // initialize v = 2 * 4
    A<4> b = {2}; // initialize v to 2
    std::cout << a.v << " " << b.v << std::endl;
}
```

I want to see "8 2". What I get is "8 8".

I'd like a way to initialize v either through constructor or through some other method to avoid constructor. I've researched initializer_list or aggregate initialization but I haven't found a solution. The only hack was to create a new constructor with a dummy extra parameter.

Any better ways?

Comment: To be honest, it seems like a terrible design. It's very unclear to an outsider. If you want different constructors, you might as well have different constructors with an extra disambiguating parameter.

Comment: @DeiDei But `std::vector` seems to have a similar design.

Comment: What about adding a constructor taking `std::initializer` as its parameter?

Comment: std::initializer_list?

Comment: @xskxzr, I now understand what you mean. I wish you would give a more complete answer and I'd mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should prefer member initializer list to assigning in the body of constructor, i.e.

```
A (int p): v(p * mult) {}
```

Second, if this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), I recommend you to follow other answers and change your design. As DeiDei pointed out in the comment, the interface now is unclear to an outsider.

If you still insist on this design, you can read on.

---

You can use a constructor taking an [`std::initializer_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) as parameter. When an object is list-initialized, such constructors are considered firstly. As an example:

```
#include <initializer_list>

template <int mult>
struct A {
    int v;
    A (int p): v(p * mult) {}
    A (std::initializer_list<int> l) : v(*l.begin()) {}
};
```

The defect is that the size of `std::initializer_list` cannot be determined at compile time, so you have to accept a list initializer of size greater than 1, or of size 0 which results in undefined behavior in the expression `*l.begin()`.

Of course, you can do some runtime check, for example,

```
A (std::initializer_list<int> l) {
    if (l.size() != 1) {
        /* do something */
    }
    v = *l.begin();
}
```

However, you have to suffer from efficiency loss caused by this check.

Answer (score 0):

You could keep a private constructor and use static methods that treat their arguments differently:

```
template <int mult>
class A {
    int v;
    A (int p) {
        v = p;
    }
public:
    static A<mult> constructor1(int p) {
        return A<mult>(p);
    }
    static A<mult> constructor2(int p) {
        return A<mult>(p * mult);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that the best solution was to create a container class for 'int v'. Something like:

```
#include <iostream>
struct Ac {
    int v;
};

template <int mult>
struct A : Ac {
    A (Ac p) {
        v = p.v;
    }
    A (int p) {
        v = p * mult;
    }
};

int main (void) {
    A<4> a (2); // initialize v = 2 * 4
    A<4> b = (Ac{2}); // initialize v to 2
    std::cout << a.v << " " << b.v << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: This is pretty similar to "new constructor with dummy extra parameter"

Comment: Which was my first solution. And it felt very inelegant.